# Error when trying to run Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, emulation

I've made an Android Empty Application and when I run it the smartphone emulator screen is black and the program gives me this error message:

C:\Users\asd\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 864MB.
emulator: device fd:564
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 45 61 342 608
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDetachShader:559 error 0x501

And much more of those but I didn't copy them because the post would be too large.

Answer (score 3):

Try decreasing the Requested RAM size:

From Android studio open Windows->Select Android Virtual Device Manager->Choose your device->Click Edit button->Change the RAM parameter to 700 Mb in the Memory Options->Save and run the emulator.

If it still doesn't work try decreasing the Requested RAM size more until it works.

Answer (score -1):

Stock Emulator is very Slow , Use Genymotion ,  Its Fast and starts Quickly Too .

https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download

Comment: hey it didn't worked. i mentioned path though it didn't accepting the path of genymotion plugin. can you help